# Why do breakpoints disappear in Spring Tools Suite (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

All breakpoints are removed from the debugger each time `Maven > Update Project` is executed from the project's context menu in Spring Tools Suite (version 4.12.1)? Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

**[EDIT]** Steps to reproduce:

1. Using Spring Tools Suite, select `File > New > Spring Starter Project`
2. Enter `Name: test`, `Group: com.sample`, `Artifact: test`, `Package: com.sample`.
3. Hit the NEXT button and without modifying anything the FINISH button.
4. Open the `TestApplication.java` class file in the editor and activate a breakpoint on `SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);`
5. From the project's context menu, select `Maven > Update Project` or hit `ALT+F5` and press the OK button.

Result: The previously selected break point disappears while I would expect it to remain activated.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in the current Eclipse. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @howlger I don't think the behaviour has anything to do with the actual project since it appears on any project in my environment. I edited the original question, as requested,  with steps to reproduce the behaviour. I also noticed a possible cause as mentioned in the answer below, but that's not a real solution off course.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the steps to reproduce, I noticed the `clean projects` option in the `Update Maven Project` pop-up. When you unselected this option, the breakpoint stay activated on project update. I also noticed this option gets selected automatically next time you re-run the Maven command.

Being more or less a workaround, I expect skipping clean could result in strange and unexpected behaviour. Any suggestions about a better and more permanent solutions are more than welcome.